# Loging in giving me trouble

Tags: php

I have a table for Users and it has four fields, the user_id which auto increments, username, password, and user type. I want the user  type to be either an administrator of my system and a normal user who should have less privileges on the system. I want to create a login page for my system and the form action is checklogin.php  that should have sessions and checks if the person who has logged in is of Admin type,it should direct him to the Admin page and if the one who logged in is a normal user, it should direct him to the users page. I have tried to research but cant get a specific code. how can i do that friends?

Comment: codes please, and errors please.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// DATABASE STUFF HERE

if($userType == "Admin")
{
header("Location: adminpage.php");
}
else if($userType == "User")
{
header("Location: userpage.php");
}

// do not forget to explicitly exit() the script after a redirection
exit();
?>
```

Comment: You should call exit() or die() after a header redirect, to stop execution of any subsequent code